# Android getDrawable() Deprecated / How To use Android getDrawable()

Tags: android, android-view, android-drawable

Can anyone tell me the right way of using getDrawable() , I recall last time I used it was just fine with one parameter, but now I am getting this method is deprecated error, anyone? Bellow is the snippet I am trying to use

```
 private void toggleUi() {
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.silent_icon);
    Drawable silentImage;

    if(silent) {
        silentImage = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.silent_on);
    } else {
        silentImage = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.silent_off);
    }
    imageView.setImageDrawable(silentImage);
}
```

Will be glad if anyone can help thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since API 22 you should call `ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.***)` instead of `getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.***)`.

You can see the documentation of [ContextCompat](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat.html) from the support library for more details.

Comment: actually it was not clear enough for what exactly I was trying to do. But thanks for the help.