# .getDrawable() didn't Work with Me [ Android ]

Tags: android, android-studio, android-drawable

The `.getDrawable()` didn't Work with Me and I don't know why I tried many ways with no result like [Android getDrawable() Deprecated / How To use Android getDrawable()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32765906/android-getdrawable-deprecated-how-to-use-android-getdrawable)

The app running with no errors but `.getDrawable()` didn't Work. It's crossed out. I tried to use `getDrawable(id, Theme theme)`. I replace `Null` in Theme Place in didn't work too . 
  [image: Error snapshot]

Comment: I don't understand what you're doing, neither what the exact problem is.

Comment: jotik plz follow my answers to @ARP below .. i explain all my idea and what am doing .

Comment: You should explain all necessary information in your question.

Comment: My apologies , it's my first question in Stack OverFlow .. and i explain all necessary information in my question .. and you have question's picture too ..

Comment: The image link doesn't work for me.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/TMZ80.png

Comment: Yes, the same URL. It doesn't work.

Comment: @AmeerAmmar you say you explain all the information, but what is the question? Whewre is the code? I assume your question is why is `getDrawable(int id)` crossed out for me but you do not say that in your question.

Comment: @stjepano Hi .. i need to use getDrawable(int id) ... that is the question ... and i tried many codes with no hope .

Comment: @AmeerAmmar, read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @stjepano i will read it ..thank you , about my problem can you help me ?

Comment: @AmeerAmmar Now please take a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getDrawable%28int%29), read carefully the note about deprecation and recommendation near it. Then check you target API level (in manifest file). Since the question lacks usefull information, can't help you more than that. For example, you say it does not work but how it does not work, what is the error, are you using gradle for build, if yes which version, where is the AndroidManifest.xml, what is the target APi level etc ..

Comment: @stjepano thank you i will read it now , i tried with API 15 + 21 + 22 .. i have galaxy s5 running by Lollipop 5.0 ... i don't have any errors .. that is why ask .. the codes should be run perfect .

Comment: @AmeerAmmar the method is crossed out because your IDE (I assume Android Studio by JetBrains) detected that the method is deprecated, this does not mean that the method itself won't work.

Comment: so , what should i do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        img.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.henedi, this.getTheme()));
    } else {
        img.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.henedi));
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for help @ARP But "context.getTheme()" shows with error .

Comment: Are you in an activity or in a fragment?

Comment: here my idea , i try to learn android coding by follow some tutorials and videos , the problem is in videos the code works well but not with me . 

my Project is : 
MainActivity : 2 ImageView (clickable)
secondActivity : textView + ImageView

when i click on ImageView in MainActivity , Start secondActivity With Bio about the Clicked Picture from Drawable Folder and String From Res .

Comment: If you are in an activity this.getTheme() should works

Comment: private ImageView img ;  
        img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView3) ;
        Bundle exte = getIntent().getExtras() ;
    }

    public void Gater(String mName){

        if ( mName == "henedi") {
         img.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.henedi ));

that is all what in Second Activity ..

Comment: And the code I wrote in the answer don't work in the second Activity?